# Как проверить, пуст ли layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Есть layout, в который в процессе работы приложения могут быть добавлены view  или удалены из него. Может случится так, что все view из layout будут удалены. Можно ли как-то проверить, пуст ли layout?

Примерно так:

```
if (R.id.layout1 == (пуст ?) ) {что-то там происходит}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Просто проверьте кол-во детей вашего контейнера. Если оно 0 - значит он пуст.

```
long birthTimeInMills = System.currentTimeMillis();
SomeContainerLayoutClassName someLayout = new SomeContainerLayoutClassName(context);
int numOfChildren = someLayout.getChildCount();
if(numOfChildren == 0)
{
    long lifeTimeInMills = System.currentTimeMillis() - birthTimeInMills;
    System.out.println("Контейнеру уже " + lifeTimeInMills + " миллисекунд, а у него всё ещё нет детей");
}
```